# C# form Handle property

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Is Handle property for a C# form same thing as HWND for a C++ created Window? If not, how may I get the HWND from a C# form? I need to use the form as parent for a window created in a dll file written in C++

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is the same thing.  [The documentation says as much.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Handle property of a .NET Control can be implicitly marshaled to and from an HWND in  unmanaged C++.

Just make sure it is an HWND. I've worked with a couple libraries that were intended solely for 32-bit environments, and window handles were passed as UInt32s. The Handle property will only have a value guaranteed to convert to an int without overflow if you have compiled the C# code for an x86 environment.